# jQuery method or function

Tags: jquery

As it is stated at w3schools in jQuery tutorial:

```
$(selector).action()
```

From a theoretical point of view `.action()` is a jQuery method or a jQuery function ?

Comment: See this related question about methdos and functions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/155609/difference-between-a-method-and-a-function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(selector)` is a jquery object who represents DOM element, so `.action()` is a method.